# Need assistance with authentication errors using PHPMailer

Tags: php, email, authentication, smtp, phpmailer

I'm trying to send emails to user's accounts using PHPMailer, and I've been getting these errors:

```
The following From address failed: no-reply@random: MAIL FROM command failed,Authentication Required. 
SMTP ERROR: MAIL FROM command failed Detail: Authentication Required.
SMTP server error: MAIL FROM command failed Detail: Authentication Required.
```

I've looked on overflow, the google support page supplied in the error, as well as the troubleshooting guide on github and haven't found any solutions. I know my credentials are right(I didn't post my real credentials on here). I don't want to have to allow less secure apps to access my email, because all users will have to for their emails as well. Also, I have tried oAuth2, but my redirect url(get_oauth_token.php is the file I used) couldn't find composer's autoload file : vendor/autoload.php, even though I have composer and guzzle downloaded and running.

Anyway here's the full debug output(SMTP debug is set to 2)

```
SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP g198sm11047892itb.29 - gsmtp
CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost
SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [2602:306:ccb0:63b0:1817`enter code here`:970b:44c3:889b]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-STARTTLS250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250-CHUNKING250 SMTPUTF8
CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost
SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [2602:306:ccb0:63b0:1817:970b:44c3:889b]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250-CHUNKING250 SMTPUTF8
CLIENT -> SERVER: MAIL FROM:<no-reply@random>
SERVER -> CLIENT: 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at530 5.5.1 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError g198sm11047892itb.29 - gsmtp
SMTP ERROR: MAIL FROM command failed: 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at530 5.5.1 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError g198sm11047892itb.29 - gsmtp
The following From address failed: no-reply@random: MAIL FROM command failed,Authentication Required. Learn more at https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError g198sm11047892itb.29 - gsmtp,530,5.5.1SMTP server error: MAIL FROM command failed Detail: Authentication Required. Learn more at https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError g198sm11047892itb.29 - gsmtp SMTP code: 530 Additional SMTP info: 5.5.1
Mailer Error: The following From address failed: no-reply@random: MAIL FROM command failed,Authentication Required. Learn more at https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError g198sm11047892itb.29 - gsmtp ,530,5.5.1SMTP server error: MAIL FROM command failed Detail: Authentication Required. Learn more at https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError g198sm11047892itb.29 - gsmtp SMTP code: 530 Additional SMTP info: 5.5.1SMTP server error: MAIL FROM command failed Detail: Authentication Required. Learn more at https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError g198sm11047892itb.29 - gsmtp SMTP code: 530 Additional SMTP info: 5.5.1CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 closing connection g198sm11047892itb.29 - gsmtp
```

And here's the file I'm mailing from

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
set_error_handler("var_dump");
require_once('PHPMailer/PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoLoad.php');
 require_once('PHPMailer/PHPMailer-master/class.smtp.php');
 require_once('PHPMailer/PHPMailer-master/class.phpmailer.php');
 date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');
class Mail
{

    public static function sendMail($subject,$body,$address)
    {

//Create a new PHPMailer instance

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
//Enable SMTP debugging
// 0 = off (for production use)
// 1 = client messages
// 2 = client and server messages
//Ask for HTML-friendly debug output
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';

$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 587;

$mail->SMTPAuth = false;
$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
    'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
    )
);

$mail->Username = "random@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "default";
$mail->SetFrom('no-reply@random');
$mail->addAddress($address);
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body = $body;
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Message sent!";
}
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 5):

Uh, it's failing to authenticate because you're telling it not to use authentication! Set `$mail->SMTPAuth = true;`. If you want to see useful debug output, set `SMTPDebug = 2`.

Also, there is *absolutely no need* to disable certificate checking when sending via gmail. It's a really bad idea - leave it enabled.

Comment: thanks , now i get these two errors                                                                                       SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.                                                   SMTP ERROR: Password command failed:  after looking around it seems like the only solution to that is to allow for less secure apps, but like I said, I don't want to have to allow less secure apps to access my email, because all users will have to for their emails as well, and it seems like it would be a hassle for them, are there any alternatives?

Comment: You can auth with XOAUTH2, then you don't need to enable less secure apps. Read the wiki for more info. I'd also suggest using the 6.0 branch as the oauth support is much better.

Comment: I've already tried XOAUTH2, but my redirect url(get_oauth_token.php in PHPMailer is the file I used) couldn't find composer's autoload file : vendor/autoload.php, even though I have composer and guzzle downloaded and running. Are there any other files that I should download or another way to autoload that file? I was trying to use google cloud platform

Comment: [As the readme says](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer#installation--loading), `autoload.php` is created by composer; it's not part of PHPMailer itself. Use composer to add PHPMailer to *your* app; don't try to build a script in PHPMailer's own folder.